# Mysql top 2 events query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am developing a sign in/out form using MySQL and Visual Basic. The query I have right now only shows the most recent event of each user but I want the top two events to show (ie: when he/she signed in and when he/she signed out.

I have a table called `event` with the following fields:

```
Event_ID   
User_BannerID   
Class_ID   
Timestamp    
Status    
Creator

SELECT CONCAT(u.lastname, ', ', u.firstname) AS Name
   , s.class AS Class
   , DATE_FORMAT(e.timestamp,'%b %d %Y - %r') AS DateTime
   , e.status AS Status                
FROM event e, user u, status s   
WHERE e.user_bannerid = u.user_bannerid
   AND e.class_id = s.class_id
   AND event_id IN
   (
      SELECT MAX(event_id)
      FROM event e
      GROUP BY e.user_bannerid
   )
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the LIMIT clause combined with proper ORDER BY in SELECT sentence:

```
SELECT ...
FROM theTable
WHERE ...
LIMIT 2
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: im using mysql 5.2 and it says:
Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the section called "Select the top N rows from each group" in [this article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/).

Comment: Thanks guys but now i need another help, i have a dropdown manu of in/out i want to block my users from clicking in or out twice. if they choose in, they must choose out when they come back.

im using Visual Basic

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
AND event_id IN
(
  SELECT event_id
  FROM (SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY event_id DESC LIMIT 2) e
)
```

Source for the workaround: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?86,14788,14788 and its reply, linked at the bottom. Tested on 5.1